# Sharepoint 2013 - webpart SAP, div - not 100% - only IE -

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, isapi

I have problem with sharepoint 2013. We have SAP web part, but its not loading correctly - with 100% height...
Any suggestions? The problem is only in IE (10, 11) - in older, hard to say. Chrome, FF no problem. When I remove with item inspector css - position:absolute; on div, is everything alright.

[image: [img]http://s4.postimg.org/baxih0yzd/sharepoint.jpg[/img]]

Comment: In the webpart properties have you tried to put an explicit height value something like `1000px`?

Comment: I dont have 50 points to response, but yes, I've set 1000px height, but webpart does nothing. I guess this is css problem? Its strange, when I unmark and mark position:relative, everything is correct.